# error starting 'sbt' inside project directory

Tags: scala, sbt

I am learning functional programming on Coursera with Scala. To attempt an assignment, I need to start 'sbt' in a project directory. I am following the instructions here: https://class.coursera.org/progfun-004/assignment/view?assignment_id=2

This is the error I got. I am sure that there's a build.sbt file and src folder within the project directory, but somehow sbt fails on me. Any ideas?

```
alex@alex-K46CM:~/progfun-assignments/example  
$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /home/alex/progfun-assignments/example/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /home/alex/progfun-assignments/example/project
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to /home/alex/progfun-assignments/example/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
[error] error while loading <root>, zip file is empty
scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found.
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModuleOrClass(Definitions.scala:655)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.getModule(Definitions.scala:605)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackage(Definitions.scala:145)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.ScalaPackageClass(Definitions.scala:146)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.AnyClass(Definitions.scala:176)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.init(Definitions.scala:814)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:697)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:86)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.liftedTree1$1(CompilerInterface.scala:72)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:72)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:35)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:29)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:101)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:70)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:88)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:60)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:24)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:22)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.cycle(Incremental.scala:52)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:29)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:20)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:96)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:44)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:31)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:79)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:574)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:574)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (compile:compile) scala.tools.nsc.MissingRequirementError: object scala not found.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Comment: Give the following alternative sbt invoker a go; it is superior to the default one in just about every way.  https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras

Comment: try to remove (or rename) `build.sbt` and run sbt. if same error, your sbt installation is broken

Comment: @wedens i removed the build.sbt and yes still the same error. looks like i have to reinstall sbt then. but how do you uninstall sbt in the first place?

Comment: @wedens I have reinstalled sbt. But still same error. Any ideas?

Comment: what environment variables do you have related to scala and sbt?

Comment: also try to remove your local ivy directory  ~/.ivy2/, you may have some broken jars here

Comment: The other place where the broken jar file may be is in `~/.sbt/boot`.

Comment: @wedens thanks for the tip! I removed and sbt updated a new ivy directory for me and it worked! can you please post your comment as an answer? i'll accept it accordingly.

Comment: @jrudolph thank you too, i'll try it out when sbt fails next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove your local ivy directory ~/.ivy2/, you may have some broken jars here. also check your environment variables related to sbt and scala. you can check whether it's your project problem or not by running sbt outside of sbt project, if error still appears, than it's sbt installation or environment problem

Comment: The entire thing? That took an hour to download?