# PlayFramework activator run bug

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm new in play, and i am trying run my app, but It is happening this error:

"

```
error: error while loading <root>, zip file is empty
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    ... 

[error] scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
```

"
I need fix it, but i dont know!!!!
can anyone help me?

Comment: I found the [answer][1] !!!!!
Thanks!

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25336917/3553134